# Shell execute an EXE in Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to shell execute an exe which is stored in the isolated storage space. In silverlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently [you can't](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/150837/337083.aspx).

From the first answer on the linked article:

`You can not execute anything outside of the Silverlight sandbox.`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can do it in SL 4.0.  Check this post http://www.youpvp.com/blog/post/Silverlight-meet-ShellApplication.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In an OOB app with elevated privs, it should be possible to copy a stream to a file in the users private folders and then use Shell COM objects to run the file.

You can't do this from the browser or a standard OOB silverlight app.

Answer (score 0):

Honesty I don't see how it should be possible since that would break the whole idea of running things in a sandbox. Even raised privileges shouldn't allow it, and if it is I would rate it as a critical security flaw in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

This is very useful for me:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/183587/417015.aspx

Look the last "Ken Tuker" post:

```
private void AppLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(App.Current.HasElevatedPermissions)
                {
                string strPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\test.txt";
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strPath);
                textBlock1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
        }
```