# Launching an EXE stored in Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am downloading a set of zipped files from a remote server and I am Unzipping it and storing it in Isolated Storage. In Unzipped folder I have an Exe and I need to launch the exe after Unzipping is complete. Can any one suggest me a way to do this.My silverlight application has elevated permissions and its running Out Of Browser (OOB) . My Programming environment is VS2010 and silverlight 4 Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the answers on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154202/shell-execute-an-exe-in-isolated-storage) on this issue were quite clear.

You cannot execute code from isolated storage. This would beat the point of there being a browser sandbox to begin with.